# Allowing access to S3 - CrossDomain.xml

Tags: flash, amazon-s3, cross-domain

I am trying to understand the roll of CrossDomain.xml.
Should i have a CrossDomain.xml in my server, allowing access to s3 buckets, or a CrossDomain file in the buckets allowing access to everyone? or to someone specific?

Could you please explain me how it works?

Comment: So you should have your crossdomain.xml file within your S3 bucket. The xml should contain a node for each domain you want to allow access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load/parse xml from the same domain the .swf is served from.

If you load/parse xml from another domain, that domain should have a crossomain.xml allowing the domain on which the .swf file lives to access the data.

In your case, the domain containing the data you load should allow the domain containing the swf access specified in a crossdomain policy file.

Another alternative/cheat is to use a serverside script on the .swf's domain to load the external data and cache it/save it on the .swf's domain so it can be accessed without requiring a policy file.

For more details on crossdomain.xml check out the [specs](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html).